# Microsoft Graph v1.0 getSchedule api is slow

Tags: c#, asp.net, microsoft-graph-api

I am referencing the Microsoft Docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/calendar-getschedule?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

I'm trying to send a request to https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendar/getSchedule.
I get a successful response but sometimes the API is very slow, especially on the initial page load where it can take more than 10 seconds. When I send the request again, however, it only takes 0.3 seconds.

Below is my send request code:

```csharp
    System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = 
        delegate { return true; };

    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(
        " https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendar/getSchedule ");

    string param = "{\"schedules\":[\"" + userPrincipalName + "\"],";
    param += "\"startTime\" : {\"dateTime\": \"" + startTime
        + "\",\"timeZone\": \"Taipei Standard Time\"},";
    param += "\"endTime\" : {\"dateTime\": \"" + endTime 
        + "\",\"timeZone\": \"Taipei Standard Time\"},";
    param += "\"availabilityViewInterval\" : 60}";

    request.Method = "POST";
    request.ContentType = "application/json";
    request.Headers["Authorization"] = " Bearer " + token;
    request.Headers["Prefer"] = "outlook.timezone=\"Taipei Standard Time\"";

    using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
    {
        streamWriter.Write(param);
    }

    try
    {
        var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            WebUtility.WriteAjaxResult(true, null, result);

        }
    }
```

The slowdown is happening at `GetResponse`. I am using `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch` to calculate how long `var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();` takes. It took 14 seconds to respond.

Using Postman to send the request is faster than my backend request and more stable.

I hope someone can answer the reason for me, thanks!

Comment: Where is the slow down happening? If it's at `GetResponse`, then that's probably an issue with the API Server, not your code.

Comment: Also, you should be using a JSON Serializer (see `System.Text.Json` namespace or Newtonsoft for older versions of .NET) to create your `param` payload.

Comment: is happening at GetResponse,i use "System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch" Calculate " var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();" time,It took 14 seconds to response,I still haven't found a solution

Comment: What happens if you send a request directly, like through postman or `curl`? Is it faster?

Comment: use postman send request is faster than my backend request and stable

Comment: Outside of your code, try testing the API call in Microsoft Graph Explorer or POSTMAN and see still if you can repro the issue. Unfortunately i failed to repro the issue.